# byte vs retrieving runtime performance measurement

Tags: c#, performance, ms-access

I am doing a project of image processing in which i am copying pictures inside a byte[] in c# and matching it with some algorithm. I have placed two options inside by software, so user can select according to his/her memory requirement these are,

```
1) Stores all images in byte[]. 
2) Retrieve from Ms access database on run time.
```

Performance of both are same... So whats the difference. i thought copying them inside memory makes them run much faster then retrieving them again and again from database. Can any one kindly explain.

Images are 200 x 200 , i have core 2 duo cpu 2.2 GHZ , 4GB Ram. and i am comparing pictures bit by bit(Kindly don't tell me its not a proper method :), i know already). And i am measuring the time with the help of watch inside my form. I have 900 pictures and it takes 4 sec in retrieving the correct image, whether i use byte or retrieve through query.

```
        this.image = new byte[2][]; //----------- image is byte[][]

        this.image[0] = DI;  //-------- DI is byte[]

        this.image[1] = LI;  //--------- LI is byte
```

Comment: There should be a significant performance difference, you must be doing something unexpected, it should not take 4 seconds to retrieve the image.

Comment: That is my research. Obviously i am using a trick. but the thing is stored images in byte has same efficiency against the retrieved image at run time. and wondering why it is? Byte should be faster then that, or query retrieval should be slower.

Comment: How are you reading the byte[] into memory?  From a file?

Comment: Please see above code... I am retrieving the images from the query and storing them into byte array.

Comment: I recommend that you use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch to measure the time, this way you can make sure what you are measuring and make a more precise measurement.

Comment: i am sure there is no difference. Almost 4 sec on both... I mean reading from memory and loading into memory and reading both are different things. How can reading from memory is slower or equal to second process.

Comment: Have you tried creating some simple code that isolates your issue?  Could you post a more complete code sample?  Reading from memory will be faster, so I would start looking for issues in your code.

Comment: I already pasted the byte code through which i am storing the images information in byte array. Rest is just a query. I will paste the code but i know it wont help. Just 2 line more in that that a while loop and two brackets in which a function is close which is populating the byte array.